# How to fix '$.ajax' not defined?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I already to make simple CRUD Laravel and then i tried to make simple ORM with search feature in multiple tables.
The issue appears when i use jQuery in my Data Result, i got the error :

`$.ajax not defined`

here my `results.js` :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ...
    $.ajax({
    ...
    });
});
```

here my `layout.blade.php` :

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>NCI ORM App Example</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <style>
      ...
      </style>
      <div class="container">
         @yield('content')
      </div>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha384-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/js"></sc>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('results.js') }}"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

i tried to ask in chatGPT and recommended to make generate a new integrity and add `typ="text/javascript"` in `<script>` and change `$.ajax` to `jQuery.ajax`, still not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: move the jquery library in the header so it loads before the ajax call

Comment: @MohammadEdrisRaufi — Do not confuse `<header>` (or the HTTP header) with the `<head>`. They are very different things.

Comment: @MohammadEdrisRaufi — The Ajax call is made by `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('results.js') }}"></script>` which appears **after** the code which loads jQuery. Moving the jQuery import even higher up the page won't help anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load jQuery once and only once. Do not load jQuery and then overwrite it with a different version of jQuery.

Load the full version of **jQuery**. Do not load **jQuery slim** which doesn't include the `ajax` method.

---

In short, **remove** `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: Well Done, that's my bad. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

This is functional code:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>NCI ORM App Example</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
        
      </div>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/js"></sc>
       <script>
         $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({});
         });
         </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Just use my jQuery import script. Source: https://releases.jquery.com/

And, check your path to the js file. Maybe you need something like: {{ asset('something/result.js') }}

Comment: Previously, my path asset already fixed.